# Concat multiple dataframe with different sheet name and different columns to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to concat multiple dataframe with different sheet names and different columns, then export to excel.

```py
column = [["Banana","apple"],
["Banana","Grape"],
["Apple","Pizza"]]
for i in range(3):
    random_data = np.random.randint(10,25,size=(5,3))
    df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, columns= column[i])
```

I hope there are three sheets, with different column names given.
I've tried something like `pd.concat([sheet_df, df])`, In this case, all the columns will show in that dataframe even that df doesn't have that column, but I don't want to.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: Don't `concat` at all. Each DataFrame needs to be written separately to a different sheet.

Comment: Great, but then how to do that?

Comment: I don't think it works for me, because my dataframes are in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

...

sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']

path = r'yourpath.xlsx'
with ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    for cols, sheet in zip(column, sheets):
        random_data = np.random.randint(10,25,size=(5,2))
        df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, columns=cols)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet)
```

Comment: Nice one... But I hope the`sheets` variable could be in a loop(?) Because I have 40 sheets, and I don't want to type 40 time Sheetn.

Comment: Then use `enumerate` with `column` instead of `zip`.